# Broadband Albedo Conversion Scheme

Tags: geophysics, data-analysis, reference-request, research

I had this albedo conversion written down:
$$\alpha = 0.53\alpha_{VIS}+0.47\alpha_{NIR}$$
I had on my notes that this equation was form Collins et al (2002).
However, I cannot find where this came from at all.
Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Would be beneficial if you could give a little more info. However google got me here: "The effect of a new snow and sea ice albedo scheme on regional climate model simulations" -
Morten Køltzow. See paragraph 2.1 . He relates to Collins, but I'm not able to find it in his reference.

Comment: Thank you so much! He indeed mentions it as well.

Comment: Notice that his numbers are different from yours. If I remember correctly it says 0.53 $\alpha_{VIS}$.

Comment: Thank was a typo of mine, thanks for pointing that out as well!